# Should the "Users" group be removed from Windows Servers "Allow log on locally" Security GPO setting?

Tags: windows-server, group-policy

I know by default RDP does not allow any non-admin user to RDP into a machine unless we specify it.  But a non-admin user can logon to the machine at the console.

I was looking at the "Allow log on locally" GPO security setting under the User Rights Assignment Security Settings group and it says by default the following can log on locally:

- On workstations and servers: Administrators, Backup Operators, Power Users, Users, and Guest.
- On domain controllers: Account Operators, Administrators, Backup Operators, and Print Operators.

Isnt it a security risk allowing anyone in the "Users" group which by default "Domain Users" are a member of console access to servers?  I was always curious why Microsoft allowed the Users and Guest group access to servers.

I would think removing both Guest and Users from this security policy would be best practice for servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you've answered your question yourself correctly. Users and Guest accounts should not have the "Allow log on locally" rights on **servers**, only Administrators (and Backup Operators if necessary).

Here is a MS KBA in which security countermeasures are described:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn221980.aspx

Quote:

> "For domain controllers, assign the Allow log on locally user right
>   only to the Administrators group. For other server roles, you may
>   choose to add Backup Operators in addition to Administrators. For
>   end-user computers, you should also assign this right to the Users
>   group.
>
> Alternatively, you can assign groups such as Account Operators, Server
>   Operators, and Guests to the Deny log on locally user right."